# Multiple sort algorithm (sorting within a sorted field) in Java

Tags: java, sorting

ArrayList data example:
BJM 300 AC4507 TOM_JONES, BDM 290 DC4058 ALAN_FIELD, ADG 350 BA3240 JON_THORN

I need to sort the ArrayList above into ascending sequence of the third column within the second column within the third column?

```
 public static ArrayList sortLoad1(ArrayList<WorkLoad> loads){
    String s1, s2;
    WorkLoad temp;                                     //Some local variables
    for(int i = 0 ; i < loads.size(); i++){            //Loop forward
        for(int j = loads.size()-1; j>i  ;j--){        //Loop backward
            s1 = loads.get(j-1).getDeptCode();         //Extract 1st
            s2 = loads.get(j).getDeptCode();           //Extract 2nd
            if(i+1<loads.size()&&s1.compareTo(s2)>-1){ //Compare them lexicographically
                temp = loads.get(j-1);
                //If s1 follows s2 then switch both
                loads.set(j-1, loads.get(j));
                loads.set(j, temp);
            }//endif
        }//end loop 2
    }//end loop 1
    return loads;
}
```

Above is the code I have ATM. This sorts the first column (BJM, BDM & ADG columns) but what would I have to do to sort within the sorted data as I mentioned above?? I thought sorting 3 times, but that's not going to work is it?

I've tried the nested sort (see below) mentioned below but no joy:

```
    public static ArrayList sortLoad1(ArrayList<TeachingLoad> loads){
    String s1, s2;
    TeachingLoad temp;                                   //Some local variables
    for(int i = 0 ; i < loads.size(); i++){              //Loop throuth 
        for(int j = loads.size()-1; j>i  ;j--){          //Loop through 
            s1 = loads.get(j-1).getLecturerID();        //Extract 1st
            s2 = loads.get(j).getLecturerID();          //Extract 2nd
                if(i+1<loads.size()&&s1.compareTo(s2)>-1){  //Compare them lexicographically
                    temp = loads.get(j-1);
                    //If s1 follows s2 then switch both
                    loads.set(j-1, loads.get(j));
                    loads.set(j, temp);
                }
                else{
                    for(int k = 0 ; k < loads.size(); k++){            
                        for(int l = loads.size()-1; l>i  ;l--){     
                            s1 = loads.get(l-1).getDepartmentNumber();
                            s2 = loads.get(l).getDepartmentNumber();
                            if(k+1<loads.size()&&s1.compareTo(s2)>-1){
                                temp = loads.get(l-1);
                                loads.set(l-1, loads.get(l));
                                loads.set(l, temp);
                            }
                            else{
                                for(int m = 0 ; m < loads.size(); m++){         
                                    for(int n = loads.size()-1; n>i  ;n--){         
                                        s1 = loads.get(n-1).getSchoolCode();
                                        s2 = loads.get(n).getSchoolCode();
                                        if(m+1<loads.size()&&s1.compareTo(s2)>-1){
                                            temp = loads.get(n-1);
                                            loads.set(n-1, loads.get(n));
                                            loads.set(n, temp);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }//end loop 2
    }//end loop 1
    return loads;
}
```

Comment: What does this "of the third column within the second column within the third column" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You need to nest the sorts.

Essentially do the first comparison. If the result is not 0 then use that result.

If result is 0 then do the next comparison. Again if result is not 0 then use it.

You can continue this process for as many nested comparisons as you require.

The neatest way to implement it is as a custom comparator though. Then you can just do `Collections.sort(list, comparitor)` and it will efficiently and quickly sort the list using an appropriate algorithm for the list.

For example if you have:

```
class X {
   int a, b, c;
}

Comparator<X> comparator = new Comparator<X>() {
     public int compare(X one, X two) {
         int result = one.a-two.a;
         if (result == 0) {
             result = one.b-two.b;
             if (result == 0) {
                  result = one.c-two.c;
             }
         }
         return result;
     }
}
```

That will sort a list of X first by a, then by b, then by c.

To use it just do:

```
 Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```